# How to consume kafka frome the max offset when the offset is exist?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I've read the documentation and i found the config "auto.offset.reset" :

What to do when there is ***no initial*** offset in ZooKeeper or if an offset is out of range:

the question is that I used to consumer kafka with a group id and I want to keep the group id but abandon the old message.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do this in your consumer in `ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned`:

```
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {   
    kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(partitions);
}
```